# Coverage report for Perl modules by cpancover.com

Tags: perl, code-coverage, cpan

*cpancover.com* produces reports on the code coverage of Perl modules.

I understand it's just a webserver using Devel::Cover, but I would like to simply understand the meaning of reports like:
http://cpancover.com/latest/JSON-PP-4.02/blib-lib-JSON-PP-pm--condition.html

where a table has columns like:

- !l
- l&&!r
- l&&r

Can you, please, link a relevant document to understand this or provide me some initial guidance to these reports?

Comment: Finally comment: improved understanding of test coverage led me catch a bug on a less used method that “used to work before” 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`l` and `r` refer to the right-hand side and left-hand side of the expression, and the number represents the number of times the associated expression was true.

For example, there is a coverage of `0` for `l && !r` for the following expression:

```
exists $self->{'true'} and exists $self->{'false'}
```

That means that `0` tests cover the situation where the following is true:

```
(exists $self->{'true'}) && !(exists $self->{'false'})
```

---

Logical-and and logical-or have two inputs that can take each of two values.

```
+-----------------+-----------------+
| Left-hand side  | Right-hand side |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| False           | False           |
| False           | True            |
| True            | False           |
| True            | True            |
+-----------------+-----------------+
```

However, because of short-circuiting, Perl doesn't always evaluate the right-hand side. The cases are really the following:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| Logical AND                       |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| Left-hand side  | Right-hand side |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| False           | -               |
| True            | False           |
| True            | True            |
+-----------------+-----------------+

+-----------------------------------+
| Logical OR                        |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| Left-hand side  | Right-hand side |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| False           | False           |
| False           | True            |
| True            | -               |
+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Devel::Cover is reporting which of these sets of inputs have been tested.

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Logical AND                                            |
+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Devel::Cover label | Left-hand side  | Right-hand side |
+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| !l                 | False           | -               |
| l && !r            | True            | False           |
| l && r             | True            | True            |
+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+

+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Logical OR                                             |
+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Devel::Cover label | Left-hand side  | Right-hand side |
+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| l                  | True            | -               |
| !l && r            | False           | True            |
| !l && !r           | False           | False           |
+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

If we look at the first line of the linked page, we see

```
!l        2
l && !r   0
l && r    2
```

for

```
exists $self->{'true'} and exists $self->{'false'}
```

That means

```
!l       meaning  !(exists $self->{'true'})                               was true  2  times.
l && !r  meaning  (exists $self->{'true'}) && !(exists $self->{'false'})  was true  0  times.
l && r   meaning  (exists $self->{'true'}) && (exists $self->{'false'})   was true  2  times.
```

This means that `(exists $self->{'true'}) && !(exists $self->{'false'})` being true was never tested.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one part of documentation that provides information on the report format.

In coverage testing, as [`Devel::Cover` tells us](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Cover#UNCOVERABLE-CRITERIA), there may be places in code which cannot be checked: they are "uncoverable"

> Sometimes you have code which is uncoverable for some reason. Perhaps it is an else clause that cannot be reached, or a check for an error condition that should never happen. You can tell Devel::Cover that certain criteria are uncoverable and then they are not counted as errors when they are not exercised. In fact, they are counted as errors if they are exercised. [...]

In dealing with this one can consider statements, branches, conditions, and subroutines. The example report you provide deals with Conditions, and for that the docs say

> Because of the way in which Perl short-circuits boolean operations, there are three ways in which such conditionals can be uncoverable. In the case of `$x && $y` for example, the left operator may never be true, the right operator may never be true, and the whole operation may never be false. These conditions may be modelled thus:
>
> ```
> # uncoverable branch true
> # uncoverable condition left
> # uncoverable condition false
> if ($x && !$y) {
>     $x++;  # uncoverable statement
> }
>
> # uncoverable branch true
> # uncoverable condition right
> # uncoverable condition false
> if (!$x && $y) {
> }
> ```

With this discussion the linked report makes more sense.

Here is how I'd think of the first line in your link, for example. It is a `A && B` kind of condition and it has the following coverage of the possible cases:

- left side false --- covered in tests (two)
- left true but right false  --- *not* covered
- both left and right true   --- covered (two)

Then we click on "line 214" (it's a link) and see the overall percentile coverage (66 -- two thirds).  The color is telling and the codes can be seen on [this page](http://cpancover.com/blead/latest/coverage.html)

The docs also say that there is a variety of report formats so you may want to dig further.  However, I don't readily see where to look, what I find a little unsettling.

Comment: Thanks! I'm so new to this that probably I was even not asking the right question. Now it's clearer